# jQuery YQL json parse trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql

I am trying to parse json from a request, but I keep getting null. When I do console.log(data), it prints null.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(content) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(content);
        console.log(data);
    }, data: {
        q: 'select * from html where url="http://www.google.com"',
        format: "json"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your "content" is probably already parsed for you by jQuery. What happens when you:

```
console.log(content);
```

??

(Actually now that I think of it the content is parsed by the browser when it receives the response script body.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my question was poor. You're right if you set the dataType to jsonp, jQuery automatically parses the result as json. My question needs to be restated as to how to search the jsonp result with jQuery.

Comment: The result is just a javascript object so it can be accessed in the usual way, e.g., `content['query']` to retrieve the query etc.